# Is it possible to tell if a database is normalised just by looking at the ERM

Tags: relational-database, data-modeling, database-normalization

Is it possible to tell if a database is normalised just by looking at the ERM? What assumptions do you have just by looking at the ERM

Comment: No - the 3NF is dependent on the **data** stored in the tables, and its meaning. It's not only a structural issue that can be decided from the mere ERD diagram alone

Comment: Even if you make a whole lot of assumptions about what the relation labels (e.g. "customer") actually *mean*, without the proposed attributes and constraints (and what they mean, natch) there is no way you could make any kind of determination.

Comment: Just making a guess, but I can't say I've ever seen a system where a "`payment`" would involve more than one "`customer`"? Why would that need a M:M join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Relationship (ER) diagram will give you **an idea** about relationships between entities and helps in making assumptions about normalization, but **does not guarantee** that normalization was done. Looking at the structure, data and relationships (foreign keys) will confirm normalization.

Some assumptions:

- 1NF may have been applied. Customers, sales people, orders, payments etch. appear to be well separated
- Foreign keys may have been applied since one-many relationships are displayed
- Primary keys may have been used
- Information can be tracked from supplier through to the customer, which may make product recall easier